# Html5/JS form to underside (for www.wix.com)

Tags: html, forms, button, web

Is it possible to create a form for WIX, where you can open an "underside"?

I hope you understand what I mean... ><

[Description as picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXfaP.jpg)

Best regards :D

Comment: No, I don’t. The answer will be either “yes” or “no”. Is there something specific you want to know? Is there any code you’ve already written?

Answer (score 0):

Not without the addition of javascript.  A forms default behavior will allow you to submit inputs as query params or as form data, but will not allow you to modify the url given to the form action.

With the addition of javascript you can register a snippet to the submit event of the form or the change event of the input and change the action property.

Comment: Ok....and this works synonymous, if I insert it with WIX in an Html5 box? :P


Because I have absolutely no idea... :(

Comment: You should post this as a WIX specific question. I haven't the slightest idea of how wix works or if it will even let you write custom JS snippets.